# Android adding HTML content on a webview without space

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I am trying to add an HTML content to a web view. If the words in the HTML content are without spaces then webview keeps that particular word on the same line.I want that content to be wrapped and be on the next line.Is it possible to do that.I am attaching a sample code that can reproduce the issue.

```
  String temp="<p>WebViewallowsyoutocreateyourownwindowforviewingwebpages(orevendevelopacompletebrowser).Inthistutorial,youcreateasimpleActivitythatcanviewandnavigatewebpages.1.CreateanewprojectnamedHelloWebView.</p>";
             WebView wb=new WebView(this);
             wb.loadDataWithBaseURL("", temp, "text/html", Encoding.UTF_8.toString(),""); 
             setContentView(wb);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using proper html  tags I think because you used just paragraph it keeps on scrolling horizontally.